# How to detect that time is past midnight?

Tags: php, time

Im coding a text-based mafia game in norwegian and need help with time detection. So here's the deal. In way to delete a mysql-record if time since a player bought the product is over midnight (24 hours clock). Here is what I tried, but in unsure it's the best method:

```
// Har livvakt? (Has bodyguard)
if($this->isTheftProtected($user_id)){
  $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `UserTing` WHERE t_meta = '2' AND t_owner = '".$user_id."'");
  $rows = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

  $timeThen = date("Hi", $rows["t_time"]);
  $theNow = date("Hi");

  if($timeThen > 0000){
    // Slett produktet <- Delete here... past midnight.
  } else {
    // Behold.
  }
} else {
  return;
}
```

So, is there a better way. Should time() be considered to be used? Its really how to do this that my question is.
Regards. ;)

Comment: Every millisecond of the day except for the one exactly at 24:00:00 is *past* midnight. You're going to need to make your question a little more specific.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might need to add cronjob or just run this query before `SELECT` to delete old records.

```
DELETE FROM `t1` WHERE DATE(`created`) < CURDATE();
```

JOINS also can be used...

Comment: He could do that, but he probably wants to lower the overhead by making it only update a player's checking the 24 hour mark.

Comment: UPDATE or DELETE will consume more less the same CPU amount in this case. Further more hard DELETING = less rows = faster speed.

Comment: So @Roman Newaza, this would delele rows that are 24 hours old? ;)

Comment: No, this would delete past midnight ones. Exactly as it's been asked.

Answer (score 1):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timestampdiff

`mysql> SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE,'2003-02-01','2003-05-01 12:05:55');`

Returns 128885

So logically;

`SELECT * FROM UserTing WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, NOW(), t_time) >= (60 * 60 * 24) AND t_owner = {$user_id}`

Shows values that 24 hours older than the current time, for t_owner.

Edit 3: Make sure you are always using MySQL time comparisons with MySQL, or PHP. But not both, as there is a allowed time variance allowed between the two. (They can sometimes be off by as much as a hour with no errors.)

Comment: Version of MySQL? I assume your using MySQL 5?

Comment: I have "libmysql - 5.5.24" on a Cherokee web server (ubuntu).